# Does await always give other tasks a chance to execute?

Tags: python, async-await

I'd like to know what guarantees python gives around when a event loop will switch tasks.

As I understand it `async` / `await` are significantly different from   threads in that the event loop does not switch task based on time slicing, meaning that unless the task yields (`await`), it will carry on indefinitely.  This can actually be useful because it is easier to manage critical sections under asyncio than with threading.

What I'm less clear about is something like the following:

```py
async def caller():
    while True:
        await callee()


async def callee():
    pass
```

In this example `caller` is repeatedly `await`.  So technically it is yielding.  But I'm not clear on whether this will allow other tasks on the event loop to execute because it only yields to `callee` and that is never yielding.

That is if I awaited `callee` inside a "critical section" even though I know it won't block, am I at risk of something else unexpected happening?

Comment: async/await doesn’t do concurrency, just coroutines. An event loop has to decide about if and how it schedules coroutines. Do you have a specific event loop (asyncio, trio, curio, ...) in mind?

Comment: This might answer your question: [how does asyncio actually work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work)

Comment: Coroutines can't stop by themselves -- they cannot ``yield`` to an event loop. A custom ``__await__`` is required, and these usually ship with the event loops. Coroutines merely create the connection from the event loop to the leaf that ``yield``s.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi never the les; it is the coroutine responsible and **not** the event loop.  The event loop has no say in when a yield occurs, the coroutine does have some control if it awaits nothing.  Your first comment is misleading, because this is not a question about the behaviour of the event loop, but the behaviour of the coroutine mechanism.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right to be wary. `caller` yields from `callee`, and yields to the event loop. Then the event loop decides which task to resume. Other tasks may (hopefully) be squeezed in between the calls to `callee`. `callee` needs to await an actual blocking `Awaitable` such as `asyncio.Future` or `asyncio.sleep()`, **not** a coroutine, otherwise the control will not be returned to the event loop until `caller` returns.

For example, the following code will finish the `caller2` task before it starts working on the `caller1` task. Because `callee2` is essentially a sync function without awaiting a blocking I/O operations, therefore, no suspension point is created and `caller2` will resume immediately after each call to `callee2`.

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def caller1():
    for i in range(5):
        await callee1()

async def callee1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"called at {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def caller2():
    for i in range(5):
        await callee2()

async def callee2():
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"sync called at {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(caller1())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(caller2())
    await task1
    await task2

asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
sync called at 19:23:39
sync called at 19:23:40
sync called at 19:23:41
sync called at 19:23:42
sync called at 19:23:43
called at 19:23:43
called at 19:23:44
called at 19:23:45
called at 19:23:46
called at 19:23:47
```

But if `callee2` **awaits** as the following, the task switching will happen even if it awaits `asyncio.sleep(0)`, and the tasks will run concurrently.

```py
async def callee2():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('sync called')
```

Result:

```
called at 19:22:52
sync called at 19:22:52
called at 19:22:53
sync called at 19:22:53
called at 19:22:54
sync called at 19:22:54
called at 19:22:55
sync called at 19:22:55
called at 19:22:56
sync called at 19:22:56
```

This behavior is not necessarily intuitive, but it makes sense considering that `asyncio` was made to handle I/O operations and networking concurrently, not the usual synchronous python codes.

Another thing to note is: This still works if the `callee` awaits a coroutine that, in turn, awaits a `asyncio.Future`, `asyncio.sleep()`, or another coroutine that await one of those things down the chain. The flow control will be returned to the event loop when the blocking `Awaitable` is awaited. So the following also works.

```
async def callee2():
    await inner_callee()
    print(f"sync called at {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def inner_callee():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This example is so simple yet comprehensive. Cleared the concept in 1 shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: No. Coroutines and their respective keywords (`await`, `async with`, `async for`) only *enable* suspension. Whether suspension occurs depends on the framework used, if at all.

> Third-party async functions / iterators / context managers can act as
>   checkpoints; if you see `await <something>` or one of its friends, then
>   that might be a checkpoint. So to be safe, you should prepare for
>   scheduling or cancellation happening there.
>
> [[Trio documentation](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#checkpoints)]

---

The `await` syntax of Python is syntactic sugar around two fundamental mechanisms: `yield` to *temporarily suspend* with a value, and `return` to *permanently exit* with a value. These are the same that, say, a generator function coroutine can use:

```
def gencoroutine():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i  # temporarily suspend
    return 5     # permanently exit
```

Notably, `return` does *not* imply a suspension. It is possible for a generator coroutine to never `yield` at all.

The `await` keyword (and its sibling `yield from`) interacts with both the `yield` and `return` mechanism:

- If its target `yield`s, `await` "passes on" the suspension to its own caller. This *allows to suspend an entire stack* of coroutines that all `await` each other.
- If its target `returns`s, `await` catches the return value and provides it to its own coroutine. This allows to return a value directly to a "caller", without suspension.

**This means that `await` does *not* guarantee that a suspension occurs.** It is up to the target of `await` to trigger a suspension.

---

By itself, an `async def` coroutine can *only* `return` without suspension, and `await` to *allow* suspension. It cannot suspend by itself (`yield` does not suspend to the event loop).

```
async def unyielding():
    return 2  # or `pass`
```

**This means that `await` of *just* coroutines does *never* suspend**. Only specific awaitables are able to suspend.

---

Suspension is only possible for awaitables with a custom `__await__` method. These can `yield` directly to the event loop.

```
class YieldToLoop:
     def __await__(self):
         yield   # to event loop
         return  # to awaiter
```

**This means that `await`, directly or indirectly, of a framework's awaitable will suspend**.

The exact semantics of suspending depend on the async framework in use. For example, whether a `sleep(0)` triggers a suspension or not, or which coroutine to run instead, is up to the framework. This also extends to async iterators and context managers -- for example, many async context managers will suspend *either* on enter or exit but not both.

> [Trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#checkpoints)
>
> If you call an async function provided by Trio (`await <something in trio>`), and it doesn’t raise an exception, then it always acts as a checkpoint. (If it does raise an exception, it might act as a checkpoint or might not.)
>
> [Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)
>
> `sleep()` always suspends the current task, allowing other tasks to run.